# How can I fetch data from the database using mysqli_fetch_all?

Tags: php, mysql

```
if(isset($_POST['saveUserName'])){
    $newUserName = $_POST['newUserName'];
    $id = $_SESSION['id'];
    $sql = "UPDATE users SET user='$newUserName' WHERE id='$id';";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $result = mysqli_fetch_all($result);
}
```

This code shows me the following error:

> Warning: mysqli_fetch_all() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, bool given in C:\xampp\htdocs\loginsystem\modify.php on line 13
>   Can you tell me what's wrong in this code ???
>   Thank you..

Comment: What do you expect to fetch ? You're doing an UPDATE query

Comment: An UPDATE query will return TRUE or FALSE Only and NOT a result set

Comment: You should use error reporting. You also are open to SQL injections, parameterize your query.

Comment: Your script is wide open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's

Answer (score 3):

`mysqli_query()` function returns,

> For successful SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE, or EXPLAIN queries it will return a mysqli_result object. For other successful queries it will return TRUE. FALSE on failure.

Here, `$result` contains `true` or `false`. That's why you got that particular error message.

> The `mysqli_fetch_all()` function fetches all result rows and returns the result-set as an associative array, a numeric array, or both.

If you want to get a result set then you need to change the query to select or show something.